# Are Append Queries in a self joining table possible

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have `tblEmployee` that contains 3 fields:

1. `ID`: AutoNumber
2. `Name`: Text
3. `Supervisor`: Number [as a lookup in tblEmployee]

I wish to append new data to this table from `tblNewEmployees` that has the exact same structure as the previous table.

**Can this be done if I have the ID field as an autonumber?**

I have tried various queries (for example first appending only the Name field as step 1, and then trying with a second update query to get the supervisor) but all produced garbage, hence my question whether this is possible using AutoNumbers in the first place.

Comment: Is the issue you are facing a matter of tblNewEmployees having ID values that already exist in tblEmployee?

Comment: Among other things... yes. I also couldn't get the update to refrence the IDs correctly when that wasn't the case though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it can be done in your structure (adjacency list model) in an iterative way i.e. add the employee(s) at the top of the tree, query the database to get their auto-generated id(s), then add the employees in the next level down using the previously queried id(s), then repeat for each level down.

While possible, is it desirable? Presumably every employee already has a unique id e.g. payroll number, social security number, etc. If unsure, ask the payroll person.

Removing the dependency of the database in generating employee ids will probably free you from the aforementioned iterative process. It is preferable for inserts to be deterministic, predictable, scritpable as a one-off, etc.

Another thing to consider is that your may be modelling a tree structure when you may want a hierarchy. The examples Celko used to give: the army is a hierarchy because if you shoot your sergeant you still have to take orders from your captain; on the other hand, a river system is tree because if your dam one tributary then all downstream tributaries run dry.

It seems to me with your design, when a supervisor leaves (is deleted from the table) then you are left with an unsupervised employee (missing data, therefore data integrity is corrupted), whereas you'd want the next senior employee to take their place (hierarchy). An update in your structure could be a lot if work i.e. iterative again.

While the adjacency list model may be intuitive, it is not always the easiest to work with in SQL DML. Consider other models e.g. nested sets. That said, with Access, SQL DML is almost always painful because it doesn't support procedural SQL code in stored procs, triggers, etc; even a simple update can fail due to 'non-updatable query' (view) restrictions. So as usual, I must advise you to consider a more capable DBMS if at all possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'd upvote it twice if only for the "Celko" quote. I am however, for better or worse, stuck with Access at the moment. The hierarchy I am building would not be one where if someone got deleted it would be a MUST to have a new supervisor. I used the employee/supervisor to keep the explanation simple. THe information that i am mapping is hierarchical, but we are essentially gathering the knowledge about the hierarchy using the database, so we do not have a determenisitc key (neither of the person or the hierarchy)

Comment: ( cc: @rohrl77 ) No need for iterative code. No need to change relationship models. No need to switch databases. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41286521/2144390) for details.

Comment: @onedaywhen - *"your answer avoids iterative code by following my suggestion of 'Removing the dependency of the database in generating employee ids'"* - No, tblEmployee.ID is an AutoNumber that is automatically generated in Scenario 2.

Comment: @onedaywhen - *"You can't define a procedure, trigger, etc with a DELETE followed by an UPDATE in Access"* - In Access 2010 (per question tag) and newer you can use an After Delete [data macro](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-data-macro-b1b94bca-4f17-47ad-a66d-f296ef834200) like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE4uQ.png) to update the hierarchy.

Comment: @GordThompson: Maybe i'm not following your argument (didn't come here for an argument - sigh) but it seems to me you are are using an iterative approach in your scenario 2 e.g. insert followed by update. See my answer for appropriate wording: "SQL DML is almost always painful because it doesn't support procedural SQL code in stored procs, triggers, etc" -- if you think I made a misstatement feel free to correct it.

Comment: @onedaywhen - The solution in Scenario 2 is not iterative, it is simply (and always) a two-step process: a single INSERT followed by a single UPDATE. There is no need to "repeat for each level down".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to merge the two tables when the destination table has an AutoNumber ID. There are two possible scenarios:

#### Scenario 1: No overlap of ID values between the two tables

```
[tblEmployee]
ID  Name        Supervisor
--  ----------  ----------
 1  Director A            
 2  Manager A            1
 3  Worker A             2

[tblNewEmployees]
ID   Name        Supervisor
---  ----------  ----------
101  Director B            
102  Manager B          101
103  Worker B           102
```

Since the Access Database Engine allows us to insert arbitrary values into an AutoNumber column, this case is trivial. Just ...

```sql
INSERT INTO tblEmployee (ID, [Name], Supervisor)
SELECT ID, [Name], Supervisor FROM tblNewEmployees
```

... and we're done:

```
[tblEmployee]
ID   Name        Supervisor
---  ----------  ----------
  1  Director A            
  2  Manager A            1
  3  Worker A             2
101  Director B            
102  Manager B          101
103  Worker B           102
```

#### Scenario 2: Common ID values between the two tables

```
[tblEmployee]
ID  Name        Supervisor
--  ----------  ----------
 1  Director A            
 2  Manager A            1
 3  Worker A             2

[tblNewEmployees]
ID   Name        Supervisor
--  ----------  ----------
 2  Director B            
 5  Manager B            2
 7  Worker B             5
```

In this case we need to map the old ID values to the new ID values when the new rows are inserted. To do that, add a new column to [tblEmployee]

```sql
ALTER TABLE tblEmployee ADD oldID LONG
```

then insert the new rows, putting tblNewEmployees.ID into tblEmployee.oldID

```sql
INSERT INTO tblEmployee (oldID, [Name])
SELECT ID, [Name] FROM tblNewEmployees
```

giving us

```
[tblEmployee]
ID  Name        Supervisor  oldID
--  ----------  ----------  -----
 1  Director A                   
 2  Manager A            1       
 3  Worker A             2       
 4  Director B                  2
 5  Manager B                   5
 6  Worker B                    7
```

Then we can update the Supervisor column with the new ID values

```sql
UPDATE 
    (
        tblEmployee emp
        INNER JOIN
        tblNewEmployees new
            ON emp.oldID = new.ID
    )
    INNER JOIN
    tblEmployee emp2
        ON new.Supervisor = emp2.oldID
SET emp.Supervisor = emp2.ID
```

producing

```
[tblEmployee]
ID  Name        Supervisor  oldID
--  ----------  ----------  -----
 1  Director A                   
 2  Manager A            1       
 3  Worker A             2       
 4  Director B                  2
 5  Manager B            4      5
 6  Worker B             5      7
```

We can then drop the [oldID] column if desired.