# Merge two versions of database tables with conflicting keys

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have been asked to merge 2 Access databases. They are conflicting versions of the same file.

A database was emailed to somebody. (**I know.**) Somebody added records to the 'main' copy while somebody else added records to their copy. I want to add the new records from the 'unauthorised' copy into the main version, before utterly destroying all other copies.

Unfortunately, the database has several related tables. As would naturally happen when records are added, records in different versions have conflicting primary keys. These conflicting keys are also used as foreign keys in the new records. A foreign key reference to ID *x* means different things in the 2 versions.

Is there any hope? I thought of maybe importing it all into excel and using formulas to update the primary and foreign keys.

Is there any way to fix this programatically?

**EDIT:** Here is a picture showing the full relationships. Tables `teachers`, `tests`, and `test_results` have been changed; the others are the same in both.
[image: table relationships]

Comment: Merge databases? Access .mdb/accdb files are actually containers of many objects including table/queries/forms/reports/macros/modules. You likely mean appending data between tables of two Access files?

Comment: Also, at it stands this is too broad without specifics. To answer, yes migration in different Access dbs can be done. You can import all data into temp tables and run various queries to map keys for final table import but without seeing data or schema we cannot help further.

Comment: You could use an approach similar to "Scenario 2: Common ID values between the two tables" in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41286521/2144390).

Comment: @Parfait There are 3 tables that need appending. That would be simple, except that the new records have the same numeric ID keys in both. The keys can't just be changed since table2 and table3 reference records in table1.

Comment: @GordThompson Thank you. Unfortunately I have other tables that reference those IDs! :(

Comment: **Lesson learned**: do not treat Access databases like flatfile Excel spreadsheets (i.e., never email to different users for data intake). All users should use same backend ideally on a shared offline LAN or online O365/Sharepoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the main database, add a `Long` field named [oldID] to each table into which you need to append data. Then create Linked Tables pointing to the relevant tables in the "other" database. Since the table names are the same, the linked tables will have a '1' appended to them.

For this example, we have

```
[teachers]
ID  teacher   oldID
--  --------  -----
 1  TeacherA       
 2  TeacherB       
 3  TeacherX       

[teachers1]
ID  teacher 
--  --------
 1  TeacherA
 2  TeacherB
 3  TeacherY

[tests]
ID  test_name       teacher  oldID
--  --------------  -------  -----
 1  TeacherA_Test1        1       
 2  TeacherA_Test2        1       
 3  TeacherB_Test1        2       
 4  TeacherX_Test1        3       

[tests1]
ID  test_name       teacher
--  --------------  -------
 1  TeacherA_Test1        1
 2  TeacherA_Test2        1
 3  TeacherB_Test1        2
 4  TeacherY_Test1        3
 5  TeacherY_Test2        3
```

Make a note of where the tables diverge. In this case the [teachers] tables diverge after ID=2. So, insert the new rows from [teachers1] into [teachers], putting [teachers1].[ID] into [teachers].[oldID] so we can map old IDs to new ones:

```sql
INSERT INTO [teachers] ([teacher], [oldID])
SELECT [teacher], [ID] FROM [teachers1] WHERE [ID]>2
```

So now we have

```
[teachers]
ID  teacher   oldID
--  --------  -----
 1  TeacherA       
 2  TeacherB       
 3  TeacherX       
 4  TeacherY      3
```

Now when we append the new rows from [tests1] into [tests] we can use an INNER JOIN on [teachers].[oldID] to adjust the foreign key values that get inserted:

```sql
INSERT INTO [tests] ([test_name], [teacher], [oldID])
SELECT [tests1].[test_name], [teachers].[ID], [tests1].[ID]
FROM [tests1] INNER JOIN [teachers] ON [tests1].[teacher]=[teachers].[oldID]
```

giving us

```
[tests]
ID  test_name       teacher  oldID
--  --------------  -------  -----
 1  TeacherA_Test1        1       
 2  TeacherA_Test2        1       
 3  TeacherB_Test1        2       
 4  TeacherX_Test1        3       
 5  TeacherY_Test1        4      4
 6  TeacherY_Test2        4      5
```

Notice how the [teacher] foreign key has been mapped from the value `3` in [tests1] to `4` in [tests], reflecting the new [teachers].[ID] value for 'TeacherY'.

You can then repeat the process for child tables of [tests].

(Once the cleanup is complete you can remove the table links and drop the [oldID] columns.)

Comment: I was just about to answer with the `oldID` method! OP may need to clean out `oldID` with each database to be merged since same IDs may conflict.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to fix this programatically?

No. This must be done by a human capable of reading and understanding the data and taking decisions.

Create a query with an inner join between table one and table two, another query with an outer join between table one and table two, and another query with an outer join between table two and table one.

Now you can study the differences and decide which version of similar records to be kept and which records are completely new and should be kept - some with a new Primary Key.